# Close modal dialog on button click and refresh table angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, mean

I'm using modal dialog to add and update record. I want to close modal dialog once I click on `add` or `update` button and then refresh my table.

Following is my view code:

```
<form name="clientForm" ng-submit="check(cid)" ng-controller="ClientsController">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>            
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter Name" ng-model="client.name">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="client.email">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter Phone" ng-model="client.phone">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="well well-lg text-center bg-gray">          
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-if="cid">Save Client</button>                        
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-if="cid" title="Delete" confirmed-click="remove(client._id)" ng-confirm-click="Are you sure you want to remove?">Delete</button>                        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>            
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-if="!cid">Add Client</button>            
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

angular.module('DemoApp')
        .controller('ClientsController', function ($http, $scope, flashService) {

```
        $scope.showModal = false;
        $scope.provider = null;

        var refresh = function () {
            $http.get('/clients').success(function (response) {                    
                $scope.rowClients = response; // This will put data into our html file
            });
        };

        refresh();

        $scope.addClient = function () {
            $http.post('/clients', {param: $scope.client}).success(function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    flashService.Success('Client added successfully');
                    $scope.client = "";
                    //angular.element('.modal').modal('hide');
                    $scope.closemodal();
                    refresh();
                }
            });
        };

        $scope.showModel = function () {
            $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
        };

        $scope.closemodal = function () {
            $scope.showModal = false;
        };

        $scope.updateClient = function (id) {
            $http({
                url: '/clients/' + id,
                method: "PUT",
                data: {
                    clientsData: $scope.client
                }
            }).success(function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    flashService.Success('Client updated successfully');
                    $scope.closemodal();
                    refresh();
                }
            });
        };

        $scope.toggleModal = function (id) {
            $http.get('/clients/' + id).success(function (response) {
                $scope.cid = id;
                $scope.client = response;
                $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
            });
        };

        $scope.check = function (id) {
            if (id)
                $scope.updateClient(id);
            else
                $scope.addClient();
        };

    });
```

And here's my modal directive:

```
DemoApp.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div class="modal fade">' +
                '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
                '<div class="modal-content">' +
                '<div class="modal-header bg-primary">' +
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.title = attrs.title;

            scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function (value) {
                if (value == true)
                    $(element).modal('show');
                else
                    $(element).modal('hide');
            });

            $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
                });
            });

            $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Layout: Scripts loaded

```
    <script src="js/vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/angular/angular-route.js"></script>        
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/ClientsController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives/modal.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives/pageSelect.directive.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives/confirm.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/flashService.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>        
    <script src="js/module/smart-table.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/angular-smart-table/dist/smart-table.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see I'm calling `$scope.closemodal();` to close modal dialog and `refresh()` to refresh table after getting response from server but its not working.

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Can you share full index.html with all scripts you load, so I will be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Ygalbel: Updated. Please check modified post.

Comment: You should really update you showModal and showModel / hideModel naming, to fix the confusion. and Don't use !value as this can cause a problem. Simply use false or true. And sadly i don't see the problem just yet. I can't even see why it's working in the first place :/

Comment: @Ygalbel: @sciencefyll: I've tried this `angular.element('.modal').modal('hide');` and its closing modal but not updating table

Comment: Have you verified that the added/updated record is successfully making it to your data store?

Comment: @whipdancer: Yes. Record is updating and adding properly. After page refresh its showing on table

Comment: Can you `console.log` inside of `refresh` to verify that is executing?

Comment: Yes `refresh` is executing but `alert(response)` is working